Flutter implementing custom draggable bottomsheet
In the Telegram app, an interesting feature has been implemented: it contains a BottomSheet that, when swiped up, increases the height of its header as it reaches a specific distance from the top and displays an AppBar.
I wasn't able to implement this behavior using DraggableScrollableSheet and ChatGPT. Below, I have provided a sample code along with an image illustrating what I have in mind.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable Bottom Sheet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DraggableBottomSheetExample(),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableBottomSheetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DraggableBottomSheetExampleState createState() =>
      _DraggableBottomSheetExampleState();
}

class _DraggableBottomSheetExampleState
    extends State<DraggableBottomSheetExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _textSizeAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
    _textSizeAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 24.0, end: 48.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onScroll(double offset) {
    if (offset >= 0.8 && !_controller.isAnimating && !_controller.isCompleted) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else if (offset < 0.8 && !_controller.isAnimating && _controller.isCompleted) {
      _controller.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Draggable Bottom Sheet Example'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                      initialChildSize: 0.3,
                      minChildSize: 0.1,
                      maxChildSize: 0.8,
                      builder: (context, scrollController) {
                        scrollController.addListener(() {
                          _onScroll(scrollController.position.pixels /
                              scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                        });

                        return Container(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            controller: scrollController,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  AnimatedBuilder(
                                    animation: _controller,
                                    builder: (context, child) {
                                      return Text(
                                        'Draggable Bottom Sheet',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: _textSizeAnimation.value,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                                  Text(
                                    'Swipe up to expand or down to collapse.',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                                  // Add more content here
                                  Container(
                                    height: 500,
                                    color: Colors.blue[100],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text('Show Draggable Bottom Sheet'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


It looks like no one's quite answered your question, but the bounty is expiring in a couple minutes. Could you renew it? I think I have some ideas for you :)

@BenWeschler yes sure, you could help me with your ideas ;)

Perfect, I'll get a solution together for you tomorrow. Stay tuned!

I wonder if something is missing from the last bounty.

@DolDurma I just posted my solution! It exactly matches your image. Let me know what you think and if you need any changes!

@DolDurma Hey! Looks like the bounty is expiring shortly. I was able to exactly match the image you posted, and let me know if you need any other changes. If it works for you I would love to be the accepted answer :). Happy holidays!

This solution uses a custom Widget and RenderObject. I'll start with the code and what the result looks like and explain the solution afterward. If anyone has any questions, comments, or improvements, please leave a comment! Here's a screen recording of the output:

and here's the code. The widget you want to use is ExpandingDraggableSheet.
// Copyright (c) 2024 Benjamin Weschler.
// This code is open source and licensed under the MIT License:
// https://opensource.org/license/mit
// See the Flutter package for ExpandingDraggableSheet at:
// https://github.com/benweschler/expanding_draggable_sheet.

import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class ExpandingDraggableSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  /// The initial fractional value of the screen's height to use when displaying
  /// the modal sheet.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.5`.
  final double initialChildSize;

  /// The minimum fractional value of the screen's height to use when displaying
  /// the modal sheet.
  ///
  /// The default value is `0.25`.
  final double minimumChildSize;

  /// The unexpanded height of the expanding header at the top of the sheet.
  final double headerHeight;

  /// An optional child to display in the expanding header. The child is faded
  /// out when the header expands.
  final Widget? headerChild;

  /// The [BorderRadius] of the top corners of the sheet. Only top left and top
  /// right radii will be used.
  ///
  /// The maximum allowed radius is equal to the [headerHeight]. Larger
  /// radii will fall back on this value.
  ///
  /// The default is a circular radius of `28`, which is the default radius for
  /// a Material Design modal sheet.
  final BorderRadius? sheetBorderRadius;

  /// The background color of the modal sheet.
  ///
  /// Defaults to null and falls back to the default Material Design modal
  /// bottom sheet background color.
  final Color? backgroundColor;

  /// How the sheet should snap to its expanded position.
  ///
  /// Defaults to [SheetSnapBehavior.midpoint]. See [SheetSnapBehavior] for
  /// documentation.
  final SheetSnapBehavior snapBehavior;

  /// A callback to build the app bar. The app bar will not be interactive until
  /// it is completely faded in. Calling [Navigator.pop(context)] using the
  /// passed [BuildContext] will pop the modal sheet.
  final PreferredSizeWidget Function(BuildContext) appBarBuilder;

  /// The content of the sheet. This can not be a [Widget] that expands to fill
  /// available space, such as a [Scrollable] like [ListView]. Instead, use a
  /// [Column].
  final Widget child;

  const ExpandingDraggableSheet({
    super.key,
    this.initialChildSize = 0.5,
    this.minimumChildSize = 0.25,
    required this.headerHeight,
    this.headerChild,
    this.sheetBorderRadius,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.snapBehavior = SheetSnapBehavior.midpoint,
    required this.appBarBuilder,
    required this.child,
  }) : assert(minimumChildSize <= initialChildSize);

  @override
  State<ExpandingDraggableSheet> createState() =>
      _ExpandingDraggableSheetState();
}

class _ExpandingDraggableSheetState extends State<ExpandingDraggableSheet> {
  late final ScrollController _controller;
  final _headerAnimationPositionNotifier = ValueNotifier(0.0);

  // Only accounts for bottom overscroll, since top overscroll immediately
  // dismisses the sheet.
  final _overscrollNotifier = ValueNotifier(0.0);
  final _appBarKey = GlobalKey<_AnimatedAppBarState>();
  final _appBarOverlayController = OverlayPortalController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController(
      onAttach: (position) {
        position.addListener(_handleTopOverscroll);
        position.addListener(_handleBottomOverscroll);
      },
      onDetach: (position) {
        position.removeListener(_handleTopOverscroll);
        position.removeListener(_handleBottomOverscroll);
      },
    );
    _headerAnimationPositionNotifier.addListener(_onShowAppBar);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType can't be called in initState.
    final minimumToInitialOffset = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
        (widget.initialChildSize - widget.minimumChildSize);
    // Use a post-frame callback to ensure that the controller has been attached
    // to the scrollable.
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _controller.jumpTo(minimumToInitialOffset);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _headerAnimationPositionNotifier.removeListener(_onShowAppBar);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Handles swipe-to-dismiss on platforms where overscroll is allowed, like
  // iOS.
  void _handleTopOverscroll() {
    if (_controller.position.pixels < _controller.position.minScrollExtent) {
      _onSwipeDismiss();
    }
  }

  void _handleBottomOverscroll() {
    final overscroll =
        _controller.offset - _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
    if (overscroll > 0) {
      _overscrollNotifier.value = overscroll;
    } else if (_overscrollNotifier.value > 0) {
      _overscrollNotifier.value = 0;
    }
  }

  // Handles swipe-to-dismiss on platforms where overscroll is not
  // allowed, like Android.
  bool _handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
      final scrollDelta = notification.scrollDelta ?? 0.0;
      if (notification.metrics.pixels == 0 && scrollDelta < 0) {
        _onSwipeDismiss();
      }
    }

    // Always allow notifications to bubble up.
    return false;
  }

  void _onShowAppBar() {
    final animationPosition = _headerAnimationPositionNotifier.value;
    if (animationPosition > 0 && !_appBarOverlayController.isShowing) {
      _appBarOverlayController.show();
    } else if (animationPosition == 0 && _appBarOverlayController.isShowing) {
      _appBarOverlayController.hide();
    }
  }

  void _onSwipeDismiss() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    // If the listener is not removed, it will continue to fire as the sheet
    // continues to be over scrolled, popping the Navigator more than once.
    _controller.position.removeListener(_handleTopOverscroll);
  }

  void _updateHeaderAnimationPosition(position) {
    // Use a post-frame callback to avoid scheduling a rebuild during layout,
    // which throws an error.
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_headerAnimationPositionNotifier.value == position) return;
      _headerAnimationPositionNotifier.value = position;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // showModalBottomSheet removes the MediaQuery top padding, which includes
    // the padding to account for system UI like notches or curved screen
    // corners. Restore the top padding by getting the MediaQuery for the root
    // View.
    final viewMediaQuery = MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context));
    final double paddingHeight = widget.headerHeight;
    final appBar = widget.appBarBuilder(context);
    final double appBarHeight =
        AppBar.preferredHeightFor(context, appBar.preferredSize) +
            viewMediaQuery.padding.top;

    final BottomSheetThemeData sheetTheme = Theme.of(context).bottomSheetTheme;
    // This is the way to get the default modal sheet color in Material Design,
    // including the default for DraggableScrollableSheet.
    final backgroundColor = widget.backgroundColor ??
        sheetTheme.modalBackgroundColor ??
        sheetTheme.backgroundColor ??
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceContainerLow;

    return PopScope(
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, _) {
        if (didPop) {
          _appBarKey.currentState?.fadeOut();
        }
      },
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: viewMediaQuery,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Use an OverlayPortal to show the app bar so that features that
            // depend on the app bar's context, like automaticallyImplyLeading,
            // still work. Target the root Overlay in case there are any closer
            // Overlays that are smaller than the size of the screen.
            OverlayPortal.targetsRootOverlay(
              controller: _appBarOverlayController,
              overlayChildBuilder: (context) => Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: _AnimatedAppBar(
                  key: _appBarKey,
                  animationNotifier: _headerAnimationPositionNotifier,
                  builder: widget.appBarBuilder,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // If the scrollable is overscrolled past its max scroll extent,
            // the overscrolled portion will be a transparent hole with no
            // background color. Fill in this hole with a container that resizes
            // to the amount overscrolled.
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _overscrollNotifier,
                builder: (context, overscroll, _) => Container(
                  height: overscroll,
                  color: backgroundColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: _handleScrollNotification,
              child: CustomScrollView(
                controller: _controller,
                slivers: [
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: MaterialLocalizations.of(context)
                          .modalBarrierDismissLabel,
                      container: true,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                        // Ignore drag-based scrolling gestures.
                        onVerticalDragUpdate: (_) {},
                        onVerticalDragStart: (_) {},
                        onTap: Navigator.of(this.context).pop,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                              (1 - widget.minimumChildSize),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListenableBuilder(
                    listenable: _controller,
                    builder: (context, child) => _ExpandingSliver(
                      baseHeight: paddingHeight,
                      targetHeight: appBarHeight,
                      color: backgroundColor,
                      borderRadius: widget.sheetBorderRadius,
                      snapBehavior: widget.snapBehavior,
                      parentScrollController: _controller,
                      scrollableScrollOffset: _controller.offset,
                      updateHeaderAnimationPosition:
                          _updateHeaderAnimationPosition,
                      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: _headerAnimationPositionNotifier,
                        builder: (context, position, _) => Opacity(
                          opacity: 1 - position,
                          child: widget.headerChild,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: ColoredBox(
                      color: backgroundColor,
                      child: widget.child,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _AnimatedAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<double> animationNotifier;
  final PreferredSizeWidget Function(BuildContext) builder;

  const _AnimatedAppBar({
    super.key,
    required this.animationNotifier,
    required this.builder,
  });

  @override
  State<_AnimatedAppBar> createState() => _AnimatedAppBarState();
}

class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<_AnimatedAppBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.animationNotifier.addListener(_onNotifierUpdate);
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.animationNotifier.removeListener(_onNotifierUpdate);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  TickerFuture fadeOut() {
    return _controller.animateBack(
      0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  }

  void _onNotifierUpdate() {
    _controller.value = widget.animationNotifier.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, _) => IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: _controller.value != 1,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: _controller.value,
          child: widget.builder(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ExpandingSliver extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final double baseHeight;
  final double targetHeight;
  final Color color;
  final BorderRadius? borderRadius;
  final SheetSnapBehavior snapBehavior;
  final ScrollController parentScrollController;
  final double scrollableScrollOffset;
  final ValueChanged<double> updateHeaderAnimationPosition;

  const _ExpandingSliver({
    required this.baseHeight,
    required this.targetHeight,
    this.color = Colors.transparent,
    this.borderRadius,
    required this.snapBehavior,
    required this.parentScrollController,
    required this.scrollableScrollOffset,
    required this.updateHeaderAnimationPosition,
    super.child,
  });

  @override
  _RenderExpandingSliver createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _RenderExpandingSliver(
      baseHeight: baseHeight,
      targetHeight: targetHeight,
      color: color,
      borderRadius: borderRadius,
      snapBehavior: snapBehavior,
      scrollableScrollOffset: scrollableScrollOffset,
      parentScrollController: parentScrollController,
      updateHeaderAnimationPosition: updateHeaderAnimationPosition,
      mediaQueryTopPadding: MediaQuery.paddingOf(context).top,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
    BuildContext context,
    _RenderExpandingSliver renderObject,
  ) {
    renderObject.scrollableScrollOffset = scrollableScrollOffset;
  }
}

class _RenderExpandingSliver extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  final double baseHeight;
  final double targetHeight;
  final Color color;
  final BorderRadius? borderRadius;
  final SheetSnapBehavior snapBehavior;
  final ScrollController parentScrollController;
  final ValueChanged<double> updateHeaderAnimationPosition;
  final double mediaQueryTopPadding;

  _RenderExpandingSliver({
    required this.baseHeight,
    required this.targetHeight,
    this.color = Colors.transparent,
    this.borderRadius,
    required this.snapBehavior,
    required double scrollableScrollOffset,
    required this.parentScrollController,
    required this.updateHeaderAnimationPosition,
    required this.mediaQueryTopPadding,
  }) : _scrollableScrollOffset = scrollableScrollOffset;

  double _animationPosition = 0;

  // Whether _snapTransform has been registered as a listener for the parent
  // scrollable's isScrollingNotifier.
  bool _listeningForSnap = false;

  // Whether the parent scrollable is currently snapping.
  bool _snapping = false;

  double get _expandedHeight => targetHeight; //+ baseHeight;

  // Distance until sliver hits area to start transforming.
  double get _extentToTransform =>
      constraints.precedingScrollExtent -
      _scrollableScrollOffset -
      _expandedHeight;

  late double _previousHeight = baseHeight;
  double? _heightAdjustment;

  double _scrollableScrollOffset;

  set scrollableScrollOffset(double value) {
    if (_scrollableScrollOffset == value) return;
    _scrollableScrollOffset = value;
    // No change to size so no rebuild necessary.
    if (_extentToTransform > 0 && _previousHeight == baseHeight) return;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  void _snapTransform() {
    final double snapStartOffset;
    switch (snapBehavior) {
      case SheetSnapBehavior.start:
        snapStartOffset = 0;
      case SheetSnapBehavior.midpoint:
        snapStartOffset = (_expandedHeight - mediaQueryTopPadding) / 2;
      case SheetSnapBehavior.end:
        snapStartOffset = _expandedHeight - mediaQueryTopPadding;
      case SheetSnapBehavior.none:
        return;
    }

    // Don't snap if the sheet is scrolling or currently snapping.
    if (parentScrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.value ||
        _snapping) {
      return;
    }
    // Don't snap if the user has started scrolling the sheet content.
    if (_scrollableScrollOffset > constraints.precedingScrollExtent) return;

    final bool snapForward = _extentToTransform.abs() > snapStartOffset;
    final snapTargetOffset =
        constraints.precedingScrollExtent - (snapForward ? 0 : _expandedHeight);

    _snapping = true;
    parentScrollController
        .animateTo(
      snapTargetOffset,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.easeOutQuad,
    )
        .then((_) {
      _snapping = false;
      // This is not true of the user interrupts the snap animation.
      if (parentScrollController.offset == snapTargetOffset) {
        // Explicitly update the animation position to the appropriate bound.
        // Because the sliver introduces scroll offset corrections, it's
        // possible that the animation position will be slightly different than
        // the relevant bound of zero or one, which will causes errors in the
        // management of the app bar overlay ability to accept gestures.
        updateHeaderAnimationPosition(snapForward ? 1 : 0);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    _animationPosition =
        (-1 * _extentToTransform / _expandedHeight).clamp(0, 1);
    updateHeaderAnimationPosition(_animationPosition);
    final scrollNotifier = parentScrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier;

    if (_animationPosition > 0 && !_listeningForSnap) {
      scrollNotifier.addListener(_snapTransform);
      _listeningForSnap = true;
    } else if (_animationPosition <= 0 && _listeningForSnap) {
      scrollNotifier.removeListener(_snapTransform);
      _listeningForSnap = false;
    }

    double interpolatedHeight =
        lerpDouble(baseHeight, _expandedHeight, _animationPosition)!;
    interpolatedHeight =
        min(interpolatedHeight, constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent);

    double layoutExtent = interpolatedHeight - constraints.scrollOffset;
    layoutExtent =
        clampDouble(layoutExtent, 0, constraints.remainingPaintExtent);

    // The space between the top of this sliver and the top of the viewport.
    final remainingSpace =
        constraints.precedingScrollExtent - _scrollableScrollOffset;
    _heightAdjustment = interpolatedHeight - _previousHeight;
    _heightAdjustment = min(_heightAdjustment!, max(remainingSpace, 0));
    _previousHeight = interpolatedHeight;

    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      scrollExtent: interpolatedHeight,
      paintExtent: interpolatedHeight,
      maxPaintExtent: interpolatedHeight,
      layoutExtent: layoutExtent,
      scrollOffsetCorrection: _heightAdjustment == 0 ? null : _heightAdjustment,
    );

    child?.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints(maxExtent: baseHeight));
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final Rect bounds =
        offset & Size(constraints.crossAxisExtent, geometry!.paintExtent);

    // Make the header transparent when covered by the app bar. If the sheet is
    // popped without being scrolled down, the header won't block sheet content.
    final color = _animationPosition == 1 ? Colors.transparent : this.color;
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = color;

    final topLeftRadius = borderRadius?.topLeft ?? const Radius.circular(28);
    final topRightRadius = borderRadius?.topRight ?? const Radius.circular(28);
    final RRect rrect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      bounds,
      topLeft: Radius.lerp(topLeftRadius, Radius.zero, _animationPosition)!,
      topRight: Radius.lerp(topRightRadius, Radius.zero, _animationPosition)!,
    );

    context.canvas.drawRRect(rrect, paint);
    if (child != null) {
      context.paintChild(
        child!,
        Offset(0, offset.dy),
      );
    }
  }
}

/// Defines the point at which the modal sheet starts snapping to the app bar.
enum SheetSnapBehavior {
  /// Snap to the app bar if the modal sheet has crossed the bottom edge of the
  /// app bar.
  start,

  /// Snap to the app bar if the modal sheet has crossed the midpoint of the app
  /// bar's height.
  ///
  /// This excludes any [MediaQuery] padding encompassed by the app bar,
  /// including as any padding that would be added by a [SafeArea].
  midpoint,

  /// Snap to the app bar if the modal sheet has crossed the top edge of the app bar.
  ///
  /// This excludes any [MediaQuery] padding encompassed by the app bar,
  /// including as any padding that would be added by a [SafeArea].
  end,

  /// Disable snapping behavior.
  none,
}

You can use it like this:
// Copyright (c) 2024 Benjamin Weschler.
// This code is open source and licensed under the MIT License:
// https://opensource.org/license/mit
// See the Flutter package for ExpandingDraggableSheet at:
// https://github.com/benweschler/expanding_draggable_sheet.

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            builder: (_) => ExpandingDraggableSheet(
              headerHeight: 30,
              headerChild: Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 4,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              appBarBuilder: (context) => AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                ),
                centerTitle: false,
                title: const Row(
                  children: [Text('Gallery'), Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)],
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: List.generate(
                  40,
                  (index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item #$index')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text('Open Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

You can find an interactive example on DartPad here, and a GitHub repo for a Flutter package with this widget is here. NOTE: there's a bug in ScrollPosition.isScrollingNotifier that causes weird behavior on web (including in DartPad) and messes up the snapping feature of the sheet (see the snapBehavior parameter below), but everything works correctly on iOS/Android. You can keep track of an issue I filed for the bug here to check if it's fixed.
Documentation for Parameters
You can find full documentation for the parameters of ExpandingDraggableSheet in the comments above each parameter. Here's a short explanation of the required/important parameters:
headerChild: A widget you can add to the expanding part (the header) of the modal sheet. In this example, it's a grey drag handle.
headerHeight: The height of the expanding header before it expands. It acts as top padding for the sheet. Making this too small (like zero) might cause issues.
appBarBuilder: You add your AppBar using this builder method, which provides a BuildContext. If you need to use a BuildContext in your app bar, like if a button calls Navigator.pop(context), use the context provided by this builder.
snapBehavior: The modal sheet snaps to its expanded position. You can change how this works or disable snapping with this parameter. See its comment for more info.
child: This is the content of the modal sheet. Do not put a scrolling widget in here like ListView. Instead, use a Column and it will automatically scroll.
Short Explanation
The fact that the top of the modal sheet needs to continuously expand into the app bar as the user scrolls means that using a DraggableScrollableSheet is impractical. This is because a DraggableScrollableSheet keeps track of its position as a percentage of the available height, and if there's content at the top of the sheet that expands without constantly increasing this percentage at the same rate, the expanding content will "push" all content below it down the screen as it expands. While DraggableScrollableSheet does have a way to update its position, it doesn't have a way to update its position while simultaneously allowing the user to scroll normally.
Instead, we can create the sheet using a scrollable widget with three sections: a transparent section for the blank space above the sheet, the expanding portion, and the actual content of the sheet. In order to make sure that the expanding portion doesn't push content below it down the screen as it expands, we need to adjust the scroll position at the same rate as the expansion. To do this, we need to make our own RenderObject for the expanding portion, which gives us complete control over how it's positioned in the scrollable. The RenderObject for something in a scrolling widget is called a RenderSliver, and this exposes a parameter called scrollOffsetCorrection that allows us to do this continuous adjustment of the scroll position. To use the RenderSliver, the scrollable widget needs to be a CustomScrollView.

Here is an ExpandableBottomSheet that will transition to an AppBar when it gets near the top.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: TelegramBottomSheetDemo()));
}

class TelegramBottomSheetDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TelegramBottomSheetDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Get Public Link Bot')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            builder: (_) => const ExpandableBottomSheet(),
          ),
          child: const Text('Open Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandableBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableBottomSheet({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExpandableBottomSheet> createState() => _ExpandableBottomSheetState();
}

class _ExpandableBottomSheetState extends State<ExpandableBottomSheet> {
  double _height = 0.5;
  bool get _isExpanded => _height > 0.9;

  void _handleDrag(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _height -= details.primaryDelta! / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      _height = _height.clamp(0.3, 1.0);
    });
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      if (_height >= 0.9) {
        _height = 1.0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: _handleDrag,
      onVerticalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * _height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(_isExpanded ? 0 : 20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _SheetHeader(
              isExpanded: _isExpanded,
              onCollapse: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                // Or you can collapse the sheet instead of popping
                // setState(() => _height = 0.5);
              },
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: _SheetContent(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SheetHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SheetHeader({
    required this.isExpanded,
    required this.onCollapse,
  });

  final bool isExpanded;
  final VoidCallback onCollapse;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height:
          isExpanded ? kToolbarHeight + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top : 60,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: isExpanded ? MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top : 0,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          if (!isExpanded)
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (isExpanded)
            AppBar(
              title: const Text('Gallery'),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: onCollapse,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SheetContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SheetContent();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
        title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
        subtitle: Text('Subtitle ${index + 1}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


From your short video it seems that the app bar is not part of the modal sheet. It actually fades in on top of it. So, when the modal sheet height is over a certain threshold (let's say 90% of screen height) three things are happening:

the AppBar appears and has variable opacity based on the distance to top
the modal sheet has a variable top padding based on distance to top
the modal sheet shape (rounded corners) changes based on distance to top

A DraggableScrollableController can be used to get the sheet's height. This has two relevant properties:

size - size relative to container size (value between 0.0 and 1.0)
pixels - size in pixels

Using the size, one idea is to conditionally show the AppBar using an OverlayEntry.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class So79265423Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const So79265423Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('so79265423 Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => openModalBottomSheet(context),
          child: const Text('Open bottom sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      showDragHandle: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBar();
      },
    );
  }
}

class DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBar> createState() =>
      _DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBarState();
}

class _DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBarState extends State<DraggableScrollableSheetWithAppBar> {
  late DraggableScrollableController controller = DraggableScrollableController();
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(onControllerChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onControllerChanged() {
    if (!controller.isAttached) {
      return;
    }

    if (controller.size > 0.9 && overlayEntry == null) {
      addAppBarOverlay();
    } else if (controller.size < 0.9 && overlayEntry != null) {
      removeAppBarOverlay();
    }
  }

  void addAppBarOverlay() {
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: AppBar(
            title: const Text('AppBar Overlay'),
            leading: BackButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.animateTo(
                  0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  curve: Curves.easeOut,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry!);
  }

  void removeAppBarOverlay() {
    overlayEntry?.remove();
    overlayEntry = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      controller: controller,
      expand: false,
      snap: true,
      snapSizes: [0.2, 0.5, 1],
      initialChildSize: 0.5,
      minChildSize: 0.2,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 64),
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Similarly, the opacity of the app bar and any other properties can be animated based on modal sheet's size to obtain the desired effect. I'll leave this as an exercise to you.

This is tested and works fine:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: CustomBottomSheetDemo()));
}

class CustomBottomSheetDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBottomSheetDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Expandable Bottom Sheet Demo')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            builder: (_) => const ExpandableSheet(),
          ),
          child: const Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandableSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableSheet({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExpandableSheet> createState() => _ExpandableSheetState();
}

class _ExpandableSheetState extends State<ExpandableSheet> {
  double _currentHeightFactor = 0.5;
  bool get _isFullyExpanded => _currentHeightFactor > 0.9;

  void _onVerticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _currentHeightFactor -= details.primaryDelta! / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      _currentHeightFactor = _currentHeightFactor.clamp(0.3, 1.0);
    });
  }

  void _onVerticalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      if (_currentHeightFactor >= 0.9) {
        _currentHeightFactor = 1.0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
      onVerticalDragEnd: _onVerticalDragEnd,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * _currentHeightFactor,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(_isFullyExpanded ? 0 : 20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _SheetHeader(
              isExpanded: _isFullyExpanded,
              onCollapse: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: _SheetContent(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SheetHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SheetHeader({
    required this.isExpanded,
    required this.onCollapse,
  });

  final bool isExpanded;
  final VoidCallback onCollapse;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height:
          isExpanded ? kToolbarHeight + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top : 60,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: isExpanded ? MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top : 0,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          if (!isExpanded)
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (isExpanded)
            AppBar(
              title: const Text('Expanded Header'),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: onCollapse,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SheetContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SheetContent();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
        title: Text('List Item ${index + 1}'),
        subtitle: Text('Details for Item ${index + 1}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


thanks so much, but it doesn't the same as what i attached into the question
